# Unable to access AuthenticationAdmin service of WSO2 Identity server

Tags: authentication, wso2, apache-axis, wso2-identity-server

I have a new WSO2 Identity server. I need to access an axis web service `AuthenticationAdmin` of WSO2 3.2.3 to authenticate a user. I tried to follow  several tutorials but none helped.

`Issuing https://localhost:9443/services/AuthenticationAdmin` gives following error on browser:

> message: Access to service metadata for service: AuthenticationAdmin
>   has been forbidden
>
> description: Access to the specified resource (Access to service
>   metadata for service: AuthenticationAdmin has been forbidden) has been
>   forbidden.

And on console I get the error for the service not being found, as:

> ERROR {org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine} -  The endpoint reference
>   (EPR) for the Operation not found is /services/AuthenticationAdmin and
>   the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please
>   contact the server administrator..

Please guide me..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Change the,

   <HideAdminServiceWSDLs>false</HideAdminServiceWSDLs>

elements value to 'true'. That will give you the access to the Admin service WSDLs.

2. start the carbon server, log-in  and access the URL,
   https://localhost:9443/services/AuthenticationAdmin?wsdl
3. you should see the wsdl of the admin service.
4. Use that wsdl to code-generate the client stub or use already created jar at [1]

Once you obtain the adminCookie through this service you can use that cookie for all subsequent admin operations.

[1] http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/org/wso2/carbon/org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.stub/3.2.0/

HTH

Comment: Thanks a lot Pradeep finally I got the stuff working afetr modifying 'HideAdminServiceWSDLs' in carbon.xml as <HideAdminServiceWSDLs>false</HideAdminServiceWSDLs>

Comment: Pradeep, do you have any sample code on how to use the AuthenticationAdmin WS to authenticate/login a user? Thanks.